# Parallel/ Concurrent Updates in MS SQL Server -- how to perform? (getting around locks)

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, sql-update

I'd like multiple connections to an MS SQL Server database to make parallel/ concurrent updates to a single table, for reasons of speed/ reducing the total time it takes to execute.

The updates are made based on looking up a primary/ unique key.

Currently, this throws an error "transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process". I think it's because the table is being locked after the 1st connection runs an update transaction on the table. All subsequent connections encounter a locked table being updated and --- errors occur.

Is there a way in MS SQL Server to allow parallel/ concurrent updates to a single table?

Note: No incoming updates would ever 'be using' the same row at the same time -- they are all unique. They would be using the same table, however. Nevertheless, if I can somehow switch to "row locking" instead of table locking, would this solve the problem? Or if I can switch to "screw any locking, period" (is this referred to as uncommitted writing?) -- I would also do that, as it wouldn't affect data integrity with my process.

Let me know what you think. Thanks!

PS ... if I did "row locks" only, would my "commit size" matter in any way in regards to locking?

Comment: Only the specified row should be locked for single-row updates as long as the expression is sargable (e.g. parameter data type matches that of the primary ley column(s)).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to switch to row locking anyway if serialization of the updates is not absolutely necessary. Further you should check the isolation level and locking sequence of the read transactions on which the table is involved, because they may also be part of the deadlock scenario.

Since table locking is more restrictive than row locking, the probability to run into a deadlock is higher. Further you won't gain speed by using multiple connections because the table locks will serialize your concurrent transactions again.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. The trouble is I can't "force" row-locking only, I can only suggest it, as far as I know. SQL Server always has the final say. That said, I think the problem was I was my "commit size" was too high --- I had it at 100 rows b/c I thought it would save some time. Turns out it was just leading to more table locking. Leaving that blank (therefore 1?) seemed to have solved the issue --- for now. I'm still concerned that there's a non-zero chance a 'deadlock' will occur in the future, but who knows.

Comment: Of course you can force the transaction isolation level: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx. If you do not specify the isolation level, SQL server's default level is READ_COMMITTED which refers to rows.

Comment: Ah yes ... 'read uncommitted' would prevent an update transaction from locking anything? That would indeed be very nice.